# How to disable Firefox pop up blocker via CentOS 7 terminal

Tags: firefox, popup-blocker

Running selenium tests on a CentOS 7 minimal VM. Need to disable Firfox popup blocker. Don't have UI, need to find a way to disable using the terminal.

Any commands available for that?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set the default preferences for the profile you use to run your test instance of Firefox.

The preference which [controls](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/72fe012899a1b27d34838ab463ad1ae5b116d76b/browser/components/preferences/in-content/content.xul#105) the popup blocker behavior is `dom.disable_open_during_load`. Simply add the following entry to your [prefs.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences) file:

```
user_pref("dom.disable_open_during_load", true);
```